# EF migration to Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, migration

Is it possible to migrate EF/NHibernate entities to Oracle database with free provider(No Devart)?
I've got this message:

> No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client'. Use the SetSqlGenerator method in the target migrations configuration class to register additional SQL generators.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you come to any conclusions on this?

Comment: Yes. you can use ODP.Net from Oracle website.please visit [Entity Framework, LINQ and Model-First for the Oracle Database](http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm) and [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 12c release 3 includes the ability to Code First.  Its currently a beta 2 release, available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index-2235287.html), but seems to work well in most cases.  Will be available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html) when its in final release.